# Parse multiple $variable values from single query?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to learn a more economical way of parsing out multiple variable values from a single `mysql_fetch_array` query. I know I could write a whole series of individual queries to resolve this, but that's a lot of extra coding and queries to hit the server with and that just seems grossly inefficient.

The base query I'd like to work with is:

```sql
SELECT vehicletype, vehiclelength
FROM my_dbase.my_table
WHERE arriveday = '08/07/2013' AND process_status = 'completed'
```

`vehicletype` has one of four fixed values assigned, and `vehiclelength` has one of five fixed values assigned from option_value fields on a form page.

What I need is to parse the result of the query to count the number of records found for each pair-combination and assign a `$variable` value to each pair-combination to display in a PHP-generated table. I have four different dates that I need to run this operation for.

I've tried some iterations of creating an `array()` or using `array_count_values()` with the output of the `mysql_fetch_array` result with no success.

Comment: What does "`X` has Y fixed values assigned" means? Can you make an example of the data contained in `vehicletype` and `vehiclelength`?

Comment: `vehiclelength` will have values like "LT20", "21-25" etc assigned. `vehicletype` will have values like "car", "trailer", "RV", etc assigned. Both values are set from a value list on a form page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can try,

```
SELECT COUNT(*), vehicletype, vehiclelength 
FROM my_dbase.my_table WHERE arriveday = '08/07/2013' 
AND process_status = 'completed' and vehicletype 
in ('t1','t2','t3','t4') and vehiclelength 
IN('1','2','3','3') GROUP BY vehicletype, vehiclelength 
ORDER BY vechicletype
```

I like to let mysql do all the work.

Comment: Thanks, but when I enter that query in MySQL Query Browser, I get an empty result set with 0 rows fetched.

Comment: Did u substitute for actual types. I hope you have not used t1, t2 and henceforth.

Comment: Ah, no I did not substitute the field values. That makes all the difference. Now just have to build the $variable values from the output.

Comment: I can't get the query output to populate any PHP variables. I can see the output in MySQL Query Browser, but using any of the variable formatting methods I'm familiar with gets nothing.

Comment: I found the problem with the code: it did not like the last element of the query `ORDER BY vehicletype` without vehicletype enclosed with hashes.